# Grouping the results of a sparse pairwise matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a sparse pairwise matrix (`<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>`) that represents the proximity between a `pandas.Series` of strings using TF-IDF & cosine similarity. If dense, it would look something like a far larger version of this:

```
[[0,0,0.3,0,0.8],
 [0.1,0,0,0,0.4],
 [0,0.9,0.6,0,0],
 [1,0.9,0,0,0.8],
 [0,0.4,0.3,0,0]]
```

With both axes represented by a `Series` like the following:

```
['Smith, David', 'Davis, Jenny', 'David Smith', 'Jennings, Brian']
```

My goal is to now group similar strings (anything over a threshold, eg. 0.8) as efficiently as possible. The result could look like something like this (in any data structure, not necessarily a hash, this is just an example):

```
{
  'Smith, David': ['Smith, David', 'David Smith'],
  'Davis, Jenny': ['Davis, Jenny'],
  'Jennings, Brian': ['Jennings, Brian']
}
```

My current approach utilizes a coordinate matrix `<class 'class scipy.sparse.coo_matrix'>` and `zip` to iterate through the non-zero entries:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

cx = cosine_similarity(tf_idf_matrix, dense_output=False).tocoo()

vals = df['Names']

for row, col, data in zip(cx.row, cx.col, cx.data):
    do_something(vals[row], vals[col], data)
```

This works well, but it is pretty slow once the Series gets much above 100,000 entries and I feel like I'm missing something. Is there a more efficient approach? Perhaps something with binding the axes to the array and filtering by my threshold (0.8)?

I feel like this must be a fairly common task but googling is getting me nowhere.

---

**Update:**

I was able to greatly reduce the overhead by switching from using `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity` to using `sparse_dot_topn.awesome_cossim_topn`.

This allowed me to filter the matrix by my threshold as it was being built, thus significantly lowering the number of items to loop over and limiting the necessity to use cx.data to check which entries were above the threshold.

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for this kind of additional info - edit & update your post instead

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you are looking for something like

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [[0,0,0.3,0,0.8],
        [0.1,0,0,0,0.4],
        [0,0.9,0.6,0,0],
        [1,0.9,0,0,0.8],
        [0,0.4,0.3,0,0]]

names = ['Smith, David', 'Davis, Jenny', 'David Smith',
         'Jennings, Brian', 'Black, John']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=names, index=names)

df = df[df>0.8].unstack()

print(df[df.notnull()].reset_index())
```

```sh
        level_0          level_1    0
0  Smith, David  Jennings, Brian  1.0
1  Davis, Jenny      David Smith  0.9
2  Davis, Jenny  Jennings, Brian  0.9
```

From here you should be able to play towards your desired output.